# mscorlib.dll 2.0.5.0 (Silverlight 4) is different in SDK and runtime - missing method

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've stumbled over a strange issue, namely, as suggested in the headline, the SDK and runtime version of mscorlib.dll are not equal.

In my system I have the dll's here:

Runtime: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60831.0\
SDK: c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\

The MSDN helppage clearly indicates that AppDomain.GetAssemblies is included in Silverlight 4 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=VS.95).aspx)

The runtime version of mscorlib.dll indeed has the method - but the SDK version does NOT. The assemblies has the same version (2.0.50727).

To make things even more strange, the object browser in VisualStudio shows the path of the referenced mscorlib.dll to be the SDK version, but when digging into it, it clearly has picked up the runtimeversion - with the GetAssemblies method!!

An extra twist: In Silverlight 5 beta, the 2 libs are equal, but does not include AppDomain.GetAssemblies.

Comment: 2.0.50727 is not a Silverlight version number. It is the version number for 'desktop' .NET 2.